# upload to Google Drive folder using http

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to a specific Google Drive folder. I was able to create the folder and get a returned id value. The problem is that the file is created at the root of the drive, not in the folder that I want it uploaded to. I do a POST to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&access_token=XXXXX
```

with this header data:

```
--abc123
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{ "name": "army.jpg",
"parents": [{ "id": "1svduc2OKHfUGkW1R0KWbKTPHxQ_cv8D_" }]
}

--abc123
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

There is no http error in response to this, everything looks fine.  It's just not in the right place. I should mention I was not able to find any Google documentation on how to upload to a folder, all the examples are for java/python/node, not http. This is just a guess based on other questions I have seen on StackOverflow. Any help in getting the syntax or whatever correct is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files`, I confirmed that you are using Drive API v3. `"parents": [{ "id": "1svduc2OKHfUGkW1R0KWbKTPHxQ_cv8D_"` is used for Drive API v2. I thought that this is the reason of your issue of `the file is created at the root of the drive, not in the folder`.

Please modify your request body as follows.

#### Modified request body:

From:

```
"parents": [{ "id": "1svduc2OKHfUGkW1R0KWbKTPHxQ_cv8D_" }]
```

To:

```
"parents": ["1svduc2OKHfUGkW1R0KWbKTPHxQ_cv8D_"]
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to use the method of "Files: create" of Drive API v3. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)